# UPDATE + сложение

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Подскажите как сделать апдейт что бы значение в ячейке не перезатиралось, а добавлялось (если возможно без предварительной выборки сложения а только потом записи обратно). Инфы что то не найду по этому вопросу. Это вообще реально? если да то может кто-то знает как сделать.

Comment: Добавлялось как числа добавляются (сложение) или как строки (конкатенация)?

Comment: как числа сложение

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE `users` SET `logged_in` = `logged_in` + 1 WHERE `users.id` = 1
```

Вариант рабочий и только что протестирован

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `field` = CONCAT(field, 'literal');
```

Comment: `Добавлялось как числа добавляются (сложение) или как строки (конкатенация)?`........`как числа сложение`

Comment: Судя по тому, какой ответ принят, имелось в виду арифметическое суммирование.

Comment: Именно на это я и намекал комментарием ;)  которые взял из-под вопроса ТС